# CSS selector based on selector?

Tags: css

I am trying to set a button's background color if the menu is open. The class for the menu when open is `client-menu-open`. The class for the button is `client-header button`. Is there a way to set the button's color only if the menu is open? I have tried `.client-menu-open ~ .client-header button`, `.client-menu-open .client-header button`... Can't get anything to work.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <header>
            <button class="client-header button"/>
        </header>
        <div class="client-menu client-menu-open">...</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is the `client-menu-open` class always applied or is it applied only when the menu is open?

Comment: It is applied only when the menu is open.

Comment: Can you show your markup?

Comment: No....CSS cannot select elements prior in the DOM.

Comment: Is there a way to do it inside the `client-menu-open` class, such as is done in `@media (condition)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be (assuming the class-menu-open is added, not swapped for):

```
.client-header button client-menu-open {
background-color: #abcdef;
}
```

Comment: From looking at your code, I think you need to use javascript to swap the color after "listening" for the menu being open.  So this won't work given the above HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If your CSS is all in one line it's `.class.class`. If it's a div in a div it's `.class .class`.

So it should be:

`.client-menu.client-menu-open` for `<div class="client-menu client-menu-open">`

Only if you are working with HTML elements do you not use a `#` or `.` to select.

You can't go backwards into a previously nested element. You can probably do this with Javascript, but your question is based on CSS only.